# Which encoding should Python open function use?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

I'm getting an exception when reading a file that contains a RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK Unicode symbol. It is encoded in UTF-8 (0xE2 0x80 0x9D). The minimal example:

```py
import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())

f = open("input.txt", "r")
r.readline()
```

This script fails reading the first line even if the right quotation mark is not on the first line. The exception looks like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 102: char
acter maps to <undefined>
```

The input file is in utf-8 encoding, I've tried both with and without BOM. The default encoding returned by `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is utf-8.

This script fails on the machine with Python 3.6.5 but works well on another with Python 3.6.0. Both machines are Windows.

My questions are mostly theoretical, as this exception is thrown from external software that I cannot change, and it reads file that I don't wish to change. What should be the difference in these machines except the Python patch version? Why does vanilla `open` use cp1252 if the system default is utf-8?

Comment: open has an argument `errors=None` wehre `errors` can be `ignore`, `replace`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open also  `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is used to get the encoding

Comment: Can you try opening in binary mode "rb" to read/write binary data as is without any transformations such as converting newlines to/from platform-specific values or decoding/encoding text using a character encoding

Comment: @Epsi95, the third party software that fails, doesn't use these arguments. I didn't ask how to make the minimal example work, but why does it fail on one machine, works on another and uses cp1252.

Comment: can you print `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` in the two versions that u r running? seems encoding issue

Comment: @Epsi95, cp1251 for working and cp1252 for non working. That answers part of the question.

Comment: `Why does vanilla open use cp1252 if the system default is utf-8` ... `open` uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` to get the encoding so one should explicitly tell `utf-8` in `open`

Comment: For consistency, when I know what I am reading, I like to be explicit, `open("input.txt", "rt", encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clearly stated in Python's [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation:

> In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding.

Windows defaults to a localized encoding (`cp1252` on US and Western European versions).  Linux typically defaults to `utf-8`.

Because it is platform-dependent, use the *encoding* parameter and specify the encoding of the file explicitly.